# Exporting Coordinates of Nodes for a Minimum Spanning Tree in Networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I use Networkx in Python to generate the minimum spanning tree of the correlation in my data, and I want to find the (x,y) coordinates of the nodes. I read this question : [Exporting Layout Positions for a Graph Using NetworkX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591154/exporting-layout-positions-for-a-graph-using-networkx) and tried to apply it, but I don't really understand why I don't get the expected result.

Here is the code I use :

```
import networkx as nx
import random as rn
import pylab as pl
def create_tree(data):
    corr_matrix = define_correlation_matrix(data)
    G = nx.Graph(corr_matrix)
    pos = nx.minimum_spanning_tree(G)
    rn.seed = 5
    colors = 'bcgmry'
    components = nx.connected_components(pos)
    for i in components:
        component = pos.subgraph(i)
        nx.draw_graphviz(component,
                         node_color = colors[rn.randint(0,   len(colors)-1)], 
                         node_size = 15,
                         edge_color = [corr_matrix[i][j]*0.5 for (i,j) in component.edges()],
                         with_labels = True,
                         labels = dict([(x,data[x]) for x in component.nodes()]))
    nx.set_node_attributes(G,'pos',pos)
    print G.node
    pl.show()
```

But instead of having the coordinates I get this :

`{0: {'pos': <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x10513ea50>}, 1: {'pos': <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x10513ea50>}, 2: {'pos': <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x10513ea50>}, 3: {'pos': <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x10513ea50>}, 4: {'pos': <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x10513ea50>}, 5: {'pos': <networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x10513ea50>}}`

Do you know how I can change the code to have the coordinates ?

Thank you.

Comment: In the answer you're copying from it's `pos=nx.spring_layout(G)` so it's a dict giving coordinates of nodes.  In your code you've defined `pos` to be a minimum spanning tree (so it's a graph).

Comment: Yes, I saw when I printed the result that it was a graph, but do you think it's possible to convert this graph into a dict of coordinates ? I also tried using `nx.to_dict_of_dicts(pos)` and `nx.to_numpy_matrix(pos)` but then I don't know how to get the coordinates.

Comment: First give the graph a name other than `pos`.  `T` (for tree) might be a good choice.  `pos` is generally used to give the coordinates of nodes in the graph.  You need to recognize that the graph and the coordinates of the nodes in the graph are different things.

Comment: Then try following the answer you said you were following.  The fact that that answer used the command `nx.spring_layout` is kind of key.  If you try other commands that aren't designed to create the layout, it won't work.

Comment: Oh, but I used the `nx.spring_layout` to find the nodes, before posting the question, but when I plot the given coordinates, it looks really different from what I had after the `nx.draw_graphviz`. So it's not possible to have the same ?
Thank you for your help.